# Ocupar variables entre funciones

Tags: python, variables, python-3.7

Como mencione antes, estoy retomando python, y tengo el siguiente problema:
Quiero que si un numero es primo una variable se ponga como `True` y si no se ponga como `False`, Luego ese resultado lo quiero ocupar como parámetro e un `if`
estilo: Si es True entonces imprime esto, dejo mi codigo:

```
class Numero():


    def primo(self, numero):

        valor = range(2, numero)
        contador = 0
        for n in valor:
            if numero % n == 0:
                contador += 1
                print("divisor:", n)

        if contador > 0:
            self.primo() == False      #Esta es la parte donde se pone False o True
        else:
            self.primo() == True

    def camino(self, numero):
        if numero % 6 == 0:
            return "Multiplo de 6 men"
        if self.primo == True:          #Aquí quiero ocupar esa variable
            return "Primo"


numero = int(input("¿Qué número quieres saber si es primo? "))

miObjeto = Numero()

print(miObjeto.camino(numero))
```

Comment: `if contador > 0: self.primo() == False` significa: "Si contador es mayor que cero, ¿self.primo()  es igual a false?" Usando `==` estás realizando una comprobación, y luego no haces nada con ella? por otro lado, `self.primo()` es una función, que no veo que devuelva nada con lo cual tampoco puedes comparar con nada y luego en camino intentas usar `self.primo` que no has definido en ningún lado! Revisa tu lógica detenidamente, hay muchos fallos de conceptos básicos que deberías entender primero antes de seguir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahí lo que estás haciendo es llamando en un loop infinito al iterar dentro de `def primo()` llamar `self.primo()`

tu clase podría quedar así

```
class Numero():


    def primo(self, numero):

        valor = range(2, numero)
        contador = 0
        for n in valor:
            if numero % n == 0:
                contador += 1
                print("divisor:", n)

        return contador < 0:
     

    def camino(self, numero):
        if numero % 6 == 0:
            return "Multiplo de 6 men"
        if not self.primo():         
            return "Primo"


numero = int(input("¿Qué número quieres saber si es primo? "))

miObjeto = Numero()

print(miObjeto.camino(numero))
```

datos a tener en cuenta, cuando es un Boolean, no hace falta poner `== True` o `== false`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo, me funciono de maravilla!